# Purpose of the Perturbation function in Convex Optimization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I am trying to get into convex optimization. But I could not find a clear explanation on why we dirsturb the objective function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ like this:

$$F(x,u): \mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
F(x,0)=f(x)$$

I suspect that it helps us to achieve strong duality for a disturbed version of the original problem, which certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: It is a tool for proving results and for analyzing sensitivity.